# How to pivot and concatenate sequence of repeating rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe,

```
MachineId     Timestamp                Events    EventValue     CycleEnd       UniqueId            
7             2021-11-01 20:45:17      Attr-A       50           0                0
7             2021-11-01 20:45:44      Attr-B       1000         0                0
7             2021-11-01 21:00:00      Attr-C       5            0                0
7             2021-11-01 21:03:36      End          NULL         1                0
7             2021-11-01 21:11:43      Attr-B       1100         0                1
7             2021-11-01 21:11:44      Attr-C       2            0                1
7             2021-11-01 21:25:01      End          NULL         1                1
```

The resultant dataframe should look like,

```
MachineId    CycleId    CycleStarttime         CycleEndtime          Attr-A  Attr-B  Attr-C   End  
7            1          2021-11-01 20:45:17    2021-11-01 21:03:36   50      1000    5        NULL
7            2          2021-11-01 21:11:43    2021-11-01 21:25:01   NULL    1100    2        NULL
```

The `CycleEnd` column is related to the `Events` column. If its 1, then it means that a cycle completed.
I would like to sequentially pivot the dataframe for each cycle-end, so that I can get the values of `Events` as column with its corresponding value from the `EventValue`column.

My approach was to create a `UniqueId` column from the `CycleEnd` column by using `df['UniqueId'] = df['CycleEnd'].eq(1).shift().bfill().cumsum()` which defines each cycle individually. And then, loop over each unique Id and filter the dataframe and then store the required information to a temporary new dataframe and then append to a list. Finally concatenate.

I would like to know if there is any other more efficient (performance wise) approach for the above problem. The dataframe has hundreds of thousands of rows. Thank you!

Comment: `CycleId` is count from `UniqueId` ?

Comment: Yes, basically, each unique Id from UniqueId is a cycleId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is possible aggregate `min` and `max` datetimes per groups, then pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function like `mean`, `sum` and last join together:

```
df['UniqueId'] = df['CycleEnd'].eq(1).shift().bfill().cumsum().add(1)

df1 = (df.groupby(['MachineId','UniqueId'])
         .agg(CycleStarttime=('Timestamp','min'), CycleEndtime=('Timestamp','max')))
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['MachineId','UniqueId'],
                     columns='Events',
                     values='EventValue', 
                     aggfunc='sum')

df  = df1.join(df2).rename_axis(['MachineId','CycleId']).reset_index()
print (df)

   MachineId  CycleId      CycleStarttime        CycleEndtime  Attr-A  Attr-B  \
0          7        1 2021-11-01 20:45:17 2021-11-01 21:03:36    50.0  1000.0   
1          7        2 2021-11-01 21:11:43 2021-11-01 21:25:01     NaN  1100.0   

   Attr-C  End  
0     5.0  NaN  
1     2.0  NaN
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.
so I get a ValueError at df2 = df.pivot(['MachineId','UniqueId'],'Events','EventValue'), saying Index contains duplicate entries cannot reshape.

Comment: @MurtazaBasu - then need aggregation if multiple rows per `'MachineId','UniqueId','Events'` so change solution with aggregate `sum`

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, your DataFrame has *UniqueId* column, which facilitates grouping.

To do your task, define a function to process group of source rows as:

```
def grpProc(grp):
    rv1 = pd.Series([grp.MachineId.iloc[0], grp.UniqueId.iloc[0] + 1,
        grp.Timestamp.iloc[0], grp.Timestamp.iloc[-1]],
        index=['MachineId', 'CycleId', 'CycleStarttime', 'CycleEndtime'])
    rv2 = grp[:-1].pivot(index='MachineId', columns='Events',
        values='EventValue').iloc[0]
    return pd.concat([rv1, rv2])
```

Then run:

```
wrk = df.groupby('UniqueId').apply(grpProc)
result = wrk.unstack().reindex(columns=wrk[0].index)
result.index.name=None
```

For your source data the result is:

```
  MachineId CycleId      CycleStarttime        CycleEndtime Attr-A Attr-B  Attr-C
0         7       1 2021-11-01 20:45:17 2021-11-01 21:03:36     50   1000       5 
1         7       2 2021-11-01 21:11:43 2021-11-01 21:25:01    NaN   1100       2
```